# storing sql result into an ksh array

Tags: unix, ksh

I wrote a teradata query function that returns results which I can easily store into a variable when it returns one column. But now I want to return more than one column and store that into an array (I assume) so that I can run compare operations on the 2nd column results via an if statement.

Currently  my function for teradata look like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
td_query () { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" 
$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
     .set width 1000;
      .set titledashes off;
    $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}
```

I can then pass a query into a function and store it as a variable as such:

```
rwCnt=$(td_query "select '>'||count(*) from table;")
```

what I would like to do is query soemthing like this

```
arryData=$(td_query "select '>'||ColA, ColB from table;")
```

have that stored in a way that for each row, if ColB equals a certain value, then use the value in ColA for another procedure in the ksh script.

Comment: How are the fields seperated? Can you use `td_query "select '>'||ColA, ColB from table;" | while read ColA ColB; do ... done` ?

Comment: well, the results come back all in one string so here is what I changed the query to.."select '>'||ColA||','||ColB||'|'||....so the results come back as: rslt1a,rslt1b|rslt2a,rslt2b|rslt3a,rslt3b etc...couldnt' figure out how to get the results to come back for one row is one line.

Comment: I don't know bteq's formatting options. You can use tr to replace | with newlines and IFS for a `,` as fieldsep.

Comment: You can do one thing which I Could have done in Sybase . Take required data from the table to a temp table , set the row count to 1 .. so that the query gives only one row each time , and after each process keep deleting the row which has been processed ... In this way no formatting of data would be required in script

Comment: @WalterA I used your method and it worked...I piped it to using SED to replace | with a new line and then used IFS for fieldsep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP confirmed that the suggestion in a comment worked:
Pipe the output to another command (OP used SED) to replace | with a new line,
and use

```
| while IFS="," read ColA ColB; do
   echo "Cola = ${ColA}"
   echo "Colb = ${ColB}"
done
```